# How to Serialize List<List<T>> into JSON in C# / Unity

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

Just getting into working with JSON, and am stuck on a nested list.

The class I am trying to serialize is this:

```
[Serializable]
public class TestMainClass
{
  public List<List<Information>> additionalInformation = new List<List<Information>>();  
}

[Serializable]
public class Information
{
  public varA;
  public varB;
}
```

How the class is being initialized:

```
TestMainClass mainClass = new TestMainClass();

//Build first list of information
List<Information> firstListOfInfo = new list<Information>;
Information infoA = new Information()
{
  varA = a,
  varB = b,
}
Information infoB = new Information()
{
  varA = c,
  varB = d,
}
firstListOfInfo.Add(infoA);
firstListOfInfo.Add(infoB);

//Build other lists of information
.
.
.

//Add Lists to mainClass List
mainClass.additionalInformation.Add(firstListOfInfo);

//Add other list to the mainClass list
.
.
.
```

How the class is being serialized:

```
JsonUtility.ToJson(mainClass);
```

Output of Json:

```
{}
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: You're using fields. They need to be properties (add `{ get; set; }`).

Comment: @CodeCaster no they do not .. most of the time it is even the other way round .. Unity doesn't serialize properties .. only fields

Comment: @Matt this `[Serializable]
public class Information
{
  public varA;
  public varB;
}` is no valid c# ... what are the types of these fields? Are they serializable types?

Comment: @derHugo alright, I entirely missed that Unity was being used.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned `Newtonsoft.Json` nuget package can not be use in your case then consider you have below classes to serialize

```
[Serializable]
    public class TestMainClass
    {
        public List<List<Information>> additionalInformation = new List<List<Information>>();
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class Information
    {
        public string A;
        public string B;
    }
```

You need use and customize the Serializer as per your need, I have tried to match below serializer with  `Newtonsoft.Json`  but if you need you can modify it.

```
   public class TestMainClassConverter : System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter<TestMainClass>
        {
            public override TestMainClass Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }

            public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, TestMainClass testMain, JsonSerializerOptions options)
            {

                writer.WriteStartObject();

                writer.WriteStartArray("additionalInformation");
                foreach ( var value in testMain.additionalInformation)
                {
                    foreach (var info in value)
                    {

                        writer.WriteStartObject();

                        // Written this way to show how complex objects can be written/composed with JsonSerializer.
                        writer.WritePropertyName("A");
                        System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(writer, info.A);

                        writer.WritePropertyName("B");
                        System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(writer, info.B);

                        writer.WriteEndObject();
                    }
                }
                writer.WriteEndArray();
                writer.WriteEndObject();
            }

        }
```

Code snippet to serialize object

```
 TestMainClass mainClass = new TestMainClass();

            //Build first list of information
            List<Information> firstListOfInfo = new List<Information>();
            Information infoA = new Information()
            {
                A = "a",
                B = "b",
            };
            Information infoB = new Information()
            {
                A = "c",
                B = "d",
            };
            firstListOfInfo.Add(infoA);
            firstListOfInfo.Add(infoB);

            mainClass.additionalInformation.Add(firstListOfInfo);

            var options = new JsonSerializerOptions()
            {
                Converters = { new TestMainClassConverter() },
                WriteIndented = true
            };

            string js = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(mainClass, options);
Console.WriteLine(js);
```

Comment: Remember that the default package from newtonsoft won't work on mobile devices, use a Newtonsoft.Json fork from the asset store, like this one: https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/input-management/json-net-for-unity-11347